# React Native: HTTPS request with json body returns TypeError: Network request failed on Android

Tags: android, json, react-native, networking

Im facing an wierd network issue with React Native, all https/http requests with a json body returns

```
TypeError: Network request failed
```

This errors only occurs on **Android**, Everything is working on iOS and all other requests without json body are working.

This is the code i'm using to send a query

```
fetch(
"https://mywebsite/" + id + "/code",
{
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + (await fetchToken()),
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    code: code,
    message: message,
  }),
}
```

);

I've tried to change the url to the localhost but i'm not getting a response either
The only way to get a response from the server is to remove the

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    code: code,
    message: message,
  })
```

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application
    tools:targetApi="28"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_secutiry_config"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

I've also tried to build an APK and tried on a real phone, same issue :/

Here adb logs details :

```
    03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: TypeError: Network request failed
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:24982:33
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:29241:26
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: _callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:29161:17
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: callTimers@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:29362:19
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: __callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3003:36
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2727:31
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: __guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2954:15
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.patrinusreactnative&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2726:21
03-13 08:39:54.923 21020 21068 W ReactNativeJS: callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Any help would be appreciate !

Comment: Have you tried adding the content type in your headers like `'Content-Type': 'application/json',`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Rohit, I had to add

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

To the header of the query, I thought it was automatically calculated but no
Thanks